# ¿Qué significa el mensaje de error "remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch"?

Tags: git, netbeans

Estoy empezando a aprender a programar en **Java**, y uso el entorno de desarrollo *Netbeans*, y quería usar  **Github** como repositorio.

Aunque ya tengo algunos repositorios subidos desde mi ordenador portátil, ahora estoy intentando subir otro proyecto al mismo repositorio, pero desde mi pc de sobremesa, y siempre me lanza el mismo error, y no me sube el proyecto.

Este es el error:

> Remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch.

Traducción al español:

> El repositorio remoto contiene un commit sin combinar en la sección local.

Comment: Mira la pregunta aceptada de este post de stackoverflow en ingles, creo que te podrá ayudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027653/git-remote-repository-contains-commits-unmerged-into-the-local-branch

Comment: @Error404 te propongo publicar una respuesta basada en el contenido de ese enlace. Si lo haces, no te olvides de citar dicha pregunta y respuesta como el origen de tu publicación.

Comment: @Urco considera colocar títulos más apropiados a tu pregunta. El título debe indicar de manera concisa cuál es tu problema real. Pueden existir múltiples problemas bajo la combinación Java, NetBeans y Github, por ello conviene ser lo más específico posible desde el título.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Muchas gracias por la sugerencia. He traducido la respuesta citando la original al principio de la misma para que no haya dudas.

Comment: Dices que estás intentando subir otro proyecto a un repositorio ya existente? (sobreentiendo que ya hay código ahí). En tal caso lo ideal es tener un repositorio por cada proyecto.

Comment: Probaste ejecutar git status?

Answer (score 1):

Como dice esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027653/git-remote-repository-contains-commits-unmerged-into-the-local-branch#answer-25029847) (Stackoverflow en inglés) puedes realizar lo siguiente:

- Ves a Proyecto > Dale click derecho sobre él > Git > Navegador de repositorios

Una vez allí, sigue los siguientes pasos:

- Rama remota > Dale botón derecho > Fusionar revisión.
- Proyecto > Botón derecho > Git > Remoto > Git Push.

De esta manera se mandará tu rama local al repositorio remoto.

**P.D:** No tengo el `NetBeans` ahora mismo así que puede que las traducciones no coincidan exactamente. Sin embargo, no creo que varíen mucho de las que he indicado en la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo he intentado pero no me funciona además a mi  me sale la rama remote vacia y no me deja fundir las ramas

Comment: ¿Qué configuraciones has usado para intentar subir la rama a tu github?¿Has hecho algún commit del proyecto antes de hacer el push?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer un :

```
git add . 
git commit
```

Para que valla.
EL problema radica en que igual has echo un `git reset --hard` o algo parecido , lo mejor que puedes hacer es un :

```
git push origin <rama> --force
```

Aunque el `--force`no es aconsejable porque si trabajas con otras personas les puedes pisar los commits y el trabajo hecho. Es más aconsejable usar :

```
git push origin <rama> --force-with-lease
```

Que lo que hace  es no subirlo si hay commits de otras personas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas. La solucion que encontre es subirlo creando una nueva rama ya que al hacer un push me creaba otra rama master y logicamente no podia por que ya existia una rama master para ese repositorio.

Comment: Entendido , siempre puedes hacer luego un

Comment: `merge` de las ramas si te interesa. Aunque alguna forma existirá.